# How to install openCV package with Anaconda?

Tags: python, opencv, installation, anaconda

I am trying to install opencv with anaconda by using anaconda prompt. But it is not getting installed. I tried so many times but it showing the same error everytime.

**Error:
Anaconda Prompt:**

```
(base) C:\>conda install -c conda-forge opencv
WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
Collecting package metadata: failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/repodata.json.bz2>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

ConnectTimeout(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='repo.anaconda.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/main/win-64/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001C8E6005860>, 'Connection to repo.anaconda.com timed out. (connect timeout=9.15)'))"))
```

I am not getting what is going on here. The urls which are displayed in the error and showing that it was blocked or failed to reach, that urls are easily open in my browser window.

[image]

I am using this command for openCV installation:

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```

Please help with this for installing the openCV package with Anaconda.

Comment: probably firewall or proxy issue on your side? I can collect the package via conda...

Comment: Sosel, Thanks for the comment. I checked the firewall settings as well. It's working properly. I also try to install the package via downloading the openCV package and set the path of that package inside the Anaconda, but it's not working in my system. I don't know why.